# Object Reference Not Set to the Instance of the Object in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

Basically I'm Trying to put out on the Textbox inside the Shared Function, But i didn't access the Textbox inside the Shared Function Then i created an object of the _Default Class to access the Textbox.
After that i access the Textbox, but during running state it give me error NullReference, when i toggle i found that Textbox1.text = Nothing instead of Textbox1.text=""
Below is the Small Code which i made for sample

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles       
    Me.Load        
        TextBox1.Text = "123"        
        TestClass()        
    End Sub       

    Protected Shared Sub TestClass()       
        Dim MyF1 As New _Default       
        MyF1.TextBox1.Text = "ABC"       
    End Sub
```

Comment: c# label is not valid, please change it to vb.net

Comment: Where and when is TextBox1 created?

Comment: TextBox1 created on Design Section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TextBox1` is an instance variable of your Page class, created (probably) by the ASP.NET designer.

Thus, you cannot access it in static/shared context.

When ASP.NET receives a request, it:

- creates an instance of your _Default class
- populates the controls of _Default class according to the data that comes from the client (e.g. form data)
- does a lot of other operations which are not relevant in this context

In your scenario, you create an instance of the `_Default` class, but don't set any of its properties.

This results in the `Textbox1` property being null and that's why it throws `NullreferenceException` when used.

There are two possible solutions:

- mark the `TestClass` method as instance method (drop the `Shared` keyword)
- pass the current instance of `_Default` as a parameter to the static/shared method, like so:

  ```
  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load        
      TextBox1.Text = "123"        
      TestClass(Me)        
  End Sub       

  Protected Shared Sub TestClass(currentPage as _Default)       
      currentPage.TextBox1.Text = "ABC"       
  End Sub
  ```

<s>The second solution requires that the `TextBox1` property should be declared as `public`.</s>

(sorry if there are any VB mistakes; I'm a C# programmer ☺)

Comment: @Wolf, this control  is not static/Shared. It's access modifier is protected by default.

Comment: @PankajGarg im getting error when i `TextBox1.Text = "ABC"` this line

Comment: @Wolf **The second solution requires that the TextBox1 property should be declared as public.** No, protected access modifier is sufficient.

Comment: @PankajGarg you are right, `protected` is enough. Thanks for noticing. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @w0lf can i call `TestClass(Me)` this from other shared function

Comment: @Mano yes, provided that the other Shared function also has a reference to the current `_Default` instance (which is possible if it is passed as a parameter, just like in the case of `TestClass`)

Comment: @w0lf i have shared function for hundler to run when data arrive , and that have default permeter so how can i call _Default instance

Comment: `Protected Shared Sub TestClass1()
        Dim f = New _Default
        f.TextBox1 = New TextBox
        f.TextBox1.Text = "BHB"
        TestClass(Me)
    End Sub

    Protected Shared Sub TestClass(ByVal currentPage As _Default)
        currentPage.TextBox1.Text = "ABC"
    End Sub`

Comment: sorry, I don't really understand this question. My point was that you should use the `_Default` page instance created by ASP.Net, and having all controls properly instantiated. Normally, you shouldn't write `new _Default`

Comment: `TestClass(Me)` you called this Object in Page Load But i wanted to call this From a Shared Function when i'm trying to do i get following Error "'Me' is Valid only with an instance Method"

Comment: yes, you cannot access instance variables from a Shared context. The only way to get a reference to that object is to send it as a parameter to the shared method (be it `TestClass` or `TestClass1`)

Answer (score 0):

```
Protected Shared Sub TestClass()       
    Dim MyF1 As New _Default       // This is initializing the default page. 
    MyF1.TextBox1.Text = "ABC"     // TextBox1 is not yet initialized 
End Sub
```

Hope you got the answer. Try as mentioned below.

```
MyF1.TextBox1 As New TextBox
MyF1.TextBox1.Text = "ABC"
```

It should work without any exception.

Comment: it is giving following Error "Method arguments must be enclosed in parentheses"