# Text box not Displaying Text in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I'm Trying to use Shared Function to Display Output in TextBox, but when it is not displaying text, during Debug it shows that it has holding text , but i dont know why it is not showing text on Output
Here is it small code

```
friend shared withevents wslisten As Winsock_Orcas.Winsock      
protected sub page_Load()           
    session("me") =Me              
    Test2()          
end sub            

Protected Shared Sub TestClass(byval current as _Default)  
    current.TextBox2.Text = "BHB"   
End Sub         

Friend Shared Sub dataarrive( byval sender as object, byval e as winsock_orcas.winsockdataarrivaleventargs) handles wslisten.dataarival   
    TestClass(Session("me"))               
end sub
```

Comment: `f` has been created, but it is not added to any controls. may be `TestClass` caller knows into which control it should be added?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Object Reference Not Set to the Instance of the Object in ASP.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976822/object-reference-not-set-to-the-instance-of-the-object-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

It's because the control you created is not rendered in HTML / Not added in your form at runtime. As per your code, you are using the Textbox which is in your designer already. For that you can use below mentioned code..

```
Protected Shared Sub TestClass(ByVal currentPage As _Default)
    currentPage.TextBox2.Text = "BHB"
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
   TestClass(Me)
End Sub
```

Comment: this solution is when i call `TestClass` on load but it i wanted to call this class from another Shared Class than `TestClass(Me)` not work

Comment: Keep the class instance(Me) in session and now access the session object from your shared class.

Comment: a little bit more problem when i call these sub inside button or other event its not working using Me in session

Comment: You cannot use Non Shared member data in Shared Member function.

Comment: So now is there any solution to display Text on textbox. i need to use textbox, label, and Gridview on dataarrival event

Comment: Yes you can. Situation should be same as of `testClass(Me)`

Comment: Me is not access from dataarrival function, it is showing following error 'Me' is only valid within an instance of method. and when i use to store Me in global shared variable, it value get change when i want to use that

Comment: keyword 'Me' is not accessing from my created event